# How to make wrapped, scrollable text in cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

I've got a `ui::Text` in a `ui::Layout` and depending on the content, it overflows. I've looked into `Label::setOverflow` and `Label::setWrap` off the `ui::Text`'s `virtualRenderer` `Label`, but I don't see a way to make it scrollable and wrap.

How can I make a scrollable `ui::Text` while making sure it's wrapping text properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is, instead of using `ui::Scrollview`, to use a `ui::ListView` with only one item inside, the `ui::Text`. This lets you scroll around and dynamically resize the container, for when you change the text content of the `ui::Text`.

The key is a) setting the width of the `ui::Text` to the same size as its parent `ui::ListView` and the height to 0 and b) calling `my_listview->requestDoLayout()` on the listview anytime the text content changes, so that the scrollable area reflects that.

Here's an example of how you'd implement the large body of text scrolling into a smaller `ui::Panel`:

```cpp
ui::ListView* listview = ListView::create();
my_scene->addChild(listview);
listview->setContentSize({300, 500}); //give it whatever size

ui::Text* text = ui::Text::create("[multiline content]", "fontName.ttf", 16);
text->setTextAreaSize({300, 0}); //use that same size, but use 0 height. This auto sets overflow and wrap in the backend
listview->addChild(text);
listview->requestDoLayout(); //this triggers resizing the listview to accommodate the
                             //string content. Needs to happen each time you
                             //text->setString(new_content) too.
```